# ERROR 42830 SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo un problema al crear la tabla de la relación , el error sería el siguiente: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «cancion».
El tema es que para la relación "canción" me da esta restricción: Las canciones se identifican por su nombre y el artista que las registró, dicho nombre tambien es varchar(50). Duración, descargas y anio_creacion son enteros

Mis tablas serian estas:

```
CREATE TABLE artista (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    nombre_real VARCHAR(50),
    sigue_activo bool,
    pais_origen VARCHAR(50),
    anio_nacimiento INT
);


CREATE TABLE usuario(
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(50),
    username VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    password VARCHAR(30),
    anio_inicio INT,
    pais_usuario VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE cancion(
    nombre VARCHAR(50),
    artista SERIAL,
    duracion INT, 
    descargas_actuales INT, 
    anio_creacion INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(nombre, artista),
    CONSTRAINT fk_artista FOREIGN KEY(artista)
    REFERENCES artista(id)
)


CREATE TABLE en_lista(
    nombre_usuario VARCHAR(50),
    nombre_cancion VARCHAR(50),
    artista SERIAL,
    anio_agregacion INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(nombre_usuario, nombre_cancion, artista),
    CONSTRAINT fk_usuario FOREIGN KEY(nombre_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(username),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cancion FOREIGN KEY(nombre_cancion) REFERENCES cancion(nombre),
    CONSTRAINT fk_artista FOREIGN KEY(artista) REFERENCES artista(id)
)
```

Gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 0):

[Definición de PRIMARY KEY](http://sql.11sql.com/sql-primary-key.htm)

> La clave primaria, **`PRIMARY KEY,`** identifica de manera única cada fila
>   de una tabla.
>
> La columna definida como clave primaria (**`PRIMARY KEY`**) debe ser **`UNIQUE`**
>   (**valor único**) y **`NOT NULL`** (no puede contener valores nulos).
>
> **Cada tabla sólo puede tener una clave primaria** (**`PRIMARY KEY`**).

---

Tienes un error en la declaración de los atributos que tienen las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE cancion(
    nombre VARCHAR(50), --debería ser PK
    artista SERIAL,
    duracion INT, 
    descargas_actuales INT, 
    anio_creacion INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(nombre, artista),
    CONSTRAINT fk_artista FOREIGN KEY(artista)
    REFERENCES artista(id)
)
```

Estás intentando poner `nombre` y artista como `PK`, tienes dos errores en ella anteriormente no pusiste a continuación del atributo

```
atributo VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
```

Si es que `nombre`, fuera `pk` que pasaría si intentas insertar dos canciones que tienen alcance de nombre pero son de diferente artista?

```
INSERT INTO cancion ('Girls', 'Marina And The Diamonds',...)
INSERT INTO cancion ('Girls', 'Kid Kudi',...)
```

Existen un montón de canciones que el nombre es el mismo y esto daría un error al intentarlo

---

Segundo si es que fuera artista `PK` que pasa si intentas crear dos canciones, con nombres diferentes y mismo artista?

```
INSERT INTO cancion ('Encoder', 'Pendulum'...)
INSERT INTO cancion ('The Island', 'Pendulum'...)
```

El segundo también daría error, por una llave duplicada.

---

Lo correcto sería, poner un `id` auto-incremental si es que lo deseas:

```
CREATE TABLE cancion(
        id_cancion INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, -- aumenta 1 en 1
        nombre VARCHAR(50),
        artista SERIAL,
        duracion INT, 
        descargas_actuales INT, 
        anio_creacion INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(id_cancion),
        CONSTRAINT fk_artista FOREIGN KEY(artista)
        REFERENCES artista(id)
    )
```